# How can I find the first occurrence in a string that is not numeric in java

Tags: java, string, substring, alphanumeric

I'm working on my own method in Java that will be able to calculate math equations given a string. Basically my calculator gets something like "698+33-47*2".
I want to split the parts (using substring and finding the characters '+', '-', '*', '/') but I'm not sure how to find the first non numeric character. My method is like this so far:

```
public void DoEquation() {
  String s = storedData.getText() + data.getText();
  s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");

  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  boolean checking = true;
  while (checking) {
    if (!s.contains("+") && !s.contains("-") && !s.contains("*") && !s.contains("/") {
      checking = false;
      break;
    }
    // Logic for extracting the numbers into the list
    // Then extract the mathamatical sign and place into list
  }
  System.out.println(list); // For testing
}
```

Comment: you could use regex

Comment: In the general case, you're going to need a parser to handle an algebraic expression, especially if you have parentheses.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's a joke, right?

Comment: @Vince Do you need to deal with precedence? I.e. `3+4*5 -> 23` not `35`? How about parentheses? Unary minus signs?  Google for "expression parser java" to see what is needed.  Hint: it's recursive and a lot more complex than your code so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm just implementing a basic calculator right now, but in the future I'll be doing parentheses and stuff. But right now I'm just dealing with add, subtract, multiply, and divide

Comment: @Vince Evaluating an expression with precedence and parentheses will _require_ a recursive expression parser, because arithmetical expressions are by nature recursive.  Use what you've got so far as a basic learning exercise but recognize you will not be able to incrementally get from this to an expression parser.  It would be like trying to build a performance automobile starting with a child's tricycle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex like

`String arr1[]=temp.split("[^0-9]+");`

`String arr2[]=temp.split("[0-9]+");`

The first one will return all numbers in array as String, while second will return all operation symbols with the first element of array as null

```
eg: Input :-"698+33-47*2"
Output :- arr1=["698","33","47","2"]
arr2=[,"+","-","*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regx.  Or you can loop over each character in the string, extract a character by using charAt.  And then for each char, use Character.isDigit(char) to see if it is a digit.  You will need to think a little bit on how to handle the "-" character, which could be a negative (part of a digit) or it could be a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is splitting the numbers and operators using regex and Java 8 *(for use lambda expression)*, for example:

```
String input =  "698+33-47*2";

String[] operators = input.split("\\d"); // ----------------------> split the operators
List<String> listOperators = Arrays.stream(operators)
                                   .filter(o -> !o.isEmpty()) // -> checks the current position is not empty
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("operators: " + listOperators.toString());

String[] numbers = input.split("[*+-/]"); // ---------------------> split the numbers
List<String> listNumbers = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("numbers: " + listNumbers.toString());
```

**Output:**

- operators: [+, -, *]
- numbers: [698, 33, 47, 2]

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, you may want to write a parser for proper handling for future enhancements.

With regarding to this specific question, by using a regex should make your life easy.  Different from other answers, you can get the list of tokens with only 1 split by this regex:

```
(?<=\d)(?=[+\-*/])|(?<=[+\-*/])(?=\d)
```

This find a zero-length position that is having digit in front of it and having symbol behind it (and vice versa).

Example :

```
String input = "698+33-47*2";
String[] result = input.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[+\\-*/])|(?<=[+\\-*/])(?=\\d)")));
// result will be [698, +, 33, -, 47, *, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you do it the following way?

```
    String s =  "698+33-47*2";
    String[] numbers = s.split("[*+/-]");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
```

This will give you the `List` of `String` containing 698, 33, 47, 2.

Comment: List<String> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);

Comment: @NickZiebert, yeah. Sorry for overengineering it. Just fixed it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Just a side note: this works only by luck: `[*+-/]` means `*`, and anything between `+` and `/`.  It is just by luck `-` is in between `+` and `/`.  So, you will find the result messed up if you are splitting  `698.3+33-47*2`, or if you wrote the regex slightly differently as `[*-+/]`

Comment: imho the better solution is to escape it

Comment: @AdrianShum, I don't disagree with you. Someone else has already posted an answer that way. So I thought of posting my answer as a backup solution. I will let OP decide which one he wants to pick.